# Where are webform data stored?

Tags: html, webforms

I am new to php. I have created a form but I am unable to understand where would this form be stored when the user presses submit. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks

```
    <h1><a>Contact Us</a></h1>
    <form id="form_317009" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
                <div class="form_description">
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <p>Please enter the details here to get a quote.</p>
    </div>                      
        <ul >

                <li id="li_1" >
    <label class="description" for="element_1">Name </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_1" name="element_1" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_1"><small>Please enter your name in it.</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_3" >
    <label class="description" for="element_3">Email </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_3"><small>Please Enter a valid email so we can contact back.</small></p> 
    </li>       <li id="li_2" >
    <label class="description" for="element_2">Subject </label>
    <div>
        <textarea id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
    </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_2"><small>Please describe the package in which you are interested so we can reach you out and give you a quote.</small></p> 
    </li>

                <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="317009" />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: Use google to find out a good book for php.. It will cover basics of database too..

Comment: Use google to find out a good book for php.. It will cover basics of database too.. Search on stackoverflow. You will get a lot of questions. There various languages/platforms like php, ruby on rails, Django. I will say just try few things with php first. Learn very simple things. How to submit a form, insert queries etc. Check out php questions and get a good learning materials. Setup and start from basics and then come back with better questions, Basics are more important..Once you know the basics then checkout whats in other platform and focus on one to get good understanding:) best of luck

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It gets stored wherever you like.

You'll need to write a php app to handle the POST HTTP request from the form, which can do something to the data: put it in a database, display it back to the user, email it, throw it away, etc.

Comment: One should suggest him some good book. This and other answers on the same question are useless...

Comment: Most books I've read on programming are also useless.

Comment: @MohitJain You are wrong. There is no evidence in the original post that would suggest the author should be recommended a book to read (other than that he's new to PHP). The Q/A nature of the sites means that a person asks a direct question and gets a direct answer. Certainly suggestions to read further are warranted at times, but not in this case. Familiarize yourself with the culture of the StackExchange sites before making wild assumptions and comment-spamming an *entire* thread.

Comment: @growse, But i m sure those books are much better than your two lines answer which a beginner can never understand

Comment: If he wanted a book, he'd go to a library. He came here. This isn't a book recommendation site.

Comment: @WesleyDavid Level of question and thing specified that I am new to php gives enough evidence that guy wants to know how to do. Just telling him these two three lines cant help and nobody is free enough to write down a 100000 lines of answer for him. So we should be guidence that he can learn from his own

Comment: @growse But he needs that, else he will be keep hanging here and there. asking small basics questions..

Comment: If the answer to a question makes the questioner ask more questions to find out more about the subject matter, then the answer is a successful one. If he wants to keep asking small basic questions, let him. We're not snobs here.

Comment: But if you tell him the way he can those future questions by himself then its will something great..

Comment: Like I said before, most books are pretty useless when you've got specific questions. If they weren't, StackExchange wouldn't exist.

Comment: I have read books but I am find most of them outdated. To get the latest knowledge I ask people online here.

Comment: @MohitJain Your line of reasoning just made StackOverflow and all other forums completely unnecessary except as book clubs.

Answer (score 4):

Submitting the form sends an HTTP POST request to the URL in the `action` attribute.

You need to write server-side code to handle that POST; otherwise, nothing will happen.

Comment: Since the URL in the `action` resolves to the URL of the page itself, an error is very unlikely (unless the server is configured to disallow POST requests to that URI).

Comment: One should suggest him some good book. This and other answers on the same question are useless...

Comment: @Quentin: I strongly suspect that this is a static HTML file, and I don't think most web servers accept POSTs to static files.

Comment: @MohitJain: You're right, but I don't know of any good books.

Comment: @SLaks — Most servers do support POST requests to static files.

Comment: @Quentin: I didn't know that; updated.

Answer (score 4):

Each form in HTML has an **action** attribute. Imagine the below form:

index.php

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="check.php">
     <input type="text" name="username" />
     <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

When user press submit button, your form will send to your defined address as your form action. Here, you will send your form data to check.php file.

Then depend on what was your form sending data method , you can use $_GET or $_POST in PHP to achieve the input sent data. This is an example:

check.php

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
echo('Welcome dear '.$username);
?>
```

---

**Attention:** No security issue applied in the code above and they are just a simple code to introduce you to what you need depend on your question.

Comment: Awesome... This is nice simple explanation..

Comment: **Danger**: This example has an [XSS Security Vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Quentin, I would not learn security subjects. I just wanted to say questioner where and how the data will be sent. Just this ...

Comment: If you don't want to teach people to protect themselves against opening up security holes, don't give them code with security holes in it in the first place. Overly simplified code will give newbies a quick, warm fuzzy sensensation that will be followed up by the jabbing pain of compromised data (or worse) in the future.

Comment: Maybe you are right Quentin. But I gave my solution as simpler as possible because I thought the questioner will face to another problem ...

However, thank you for your recommendation

Answer (score 3):

The form is submitted when the button is clicked, the location it's submitted is decided by you the developer.  It can go to a database, send an email, write a file, etc.  you define this in the action attribute of the form tag.

Check out this reference for more information and how to get started: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Comment: One should suggest him some good book. This and other answers on the same question are useless...

Comment: @MohitJain so you downvote answers that are perfectly legit. I agree the question is of low quality but at least he's putting some effort forth. He didn't ask how to code the where the data is submitted he asked a general question.  I think all the answers here are perfectly fine.  Downvoted is for answers that make no sense or give the wrong information not because you don't agree with the question.  If you disagree with the question then vote to have it closed.

Comment: for a QnA site we should be guiding him properly instead of giving him solutions which completely goes like a bouncer for him..

Comment: so your saying http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php is wrong or was what I stated wrong, please elaborate how I sent him down the wrong path?  I would have to say the answer that you commented Awesome on is exactly what that site explains.

Answer (score 3):

This form would be submitted to the same page that is currently loaded (action="") and it will be stored in the $_POST array. If you want to work with this data - or store it for the future - you'll need to write code to handle the $_POST array:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST)){
     //do something here with the data.
 }

?>
```

However, as soon as the page is finished loading, the $_POST array will be discarded, so if you want to do anything long-term with the data, you'll need to store it (you can do this using sessions, cookies, write the data to files, etc).

You'll want to read a lot more about this before you start working, though.

Answer (score 2):

The `action` attribute of the `form` element determines what URL the data will be sent to.

In this case, as it is empty, the page will post to itself.

You need to have server side code to capture and store this data, otherwise it will be lost.

As for where it will be stored - that is up to you. You can save to a file, a database, send it by email or sms or even just ignore it.

Comment: @downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: One should suggest him some good book. This and other answers on the same question are useless...

Comment: @MohitJain A book suggestion is not an answer to the question, unless the question is "what's a good book for this."  Incidentally, a book recommendation question would be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to think off the data  less stored more posted and can be retrieved with

```
$_POST['guide_1'];
```

To store the data you would have to retrive the post and then store it some where your self

Also a good link to get and post in php is http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php

Comment: There is no form control with that `name`.

Comment: One should suggest him some good book. This and other answers on the same question are useless...

Comment: True but doesnt warnet going through and -1 all answers, there is also no need for a book on this subject there is so much online such as http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php